# Junit5 Test not able to inject dependency but running application normally can inject it

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit5, spring-boot-test

Currently, I am working in a project where I created `@Entity` Class , `@Repository` for storing some information. I created a service just like other existing ones and then tried that `@Service` annotated class to be injected at Controller annotated with `@RestController`. It works perfectly and was able to run the application normally without issues i.e no injection issues.

Now when I am trying to run the tests of my existing project, it fails as my service was unable to be injected into the controller class. Getting this error :

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.service.exampleService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Now I tired field and constructor injection, getting same issue every time, but I am following same patterns previously used by the project. I am quite sure the autowiring and other stuffs are properly done else the endpoints I created would not have worked.

My question is why this can happen ? i.e it works when running as spring boot application but not in test context. I tried to follow other posts but I cant follow them as most were fore Junit4

Currently I am using Junit5.

Here is how my test classes looks like

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;


@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class sampleTest{

 @Test
    public void sampletesting() throws Exception{
      ...
    }
}
```

Here are my dependencies I am using and the Spring boot version :

```
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
        id 'jacoco'
    }
 testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-core:3.5.13')
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.5.13')
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.5.13')
```

I am using Java 11

Comment: I received the same issue, I also need help on this.

Comment: Because you are using `@WebMvcTest` which will only bootstrap the web part of the application and won't include services, daos etc. If your controller uses a service you will need to add an `@MockBean` for that service to this test.

Comment: why not using `@SpringBootTest` annotation? from my experience, if you're not using `@SpringBootTest` annotation, you have to configure your context and bean manually

Comment: @M.Deinum Great!! It worked, I was not aware of it actually. Thnks for the help !

Comment: @AbhishekSengupta pls try what M. Deinum said  if you are facing this issue too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@WebMvcTest` is used in cases where you want to load only a specific part of all the available beans in the applications: web controllers (and some other web-mvc related classes, like converters, etc). It won't load any service and this is done intentionally:

Using `@WebMvcTest` implies that you want to test the controller code (all the annotations are defined correctly, etc.). Usually in this kind of tests you'll call controller method, with something called `mockMvc` and will check for expected result

You can read [here for example](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-web-controller-test/) about this kind of tests. Usually the controllers will have injected services, in this case you should use `@MockBean` on the service.

So strictly speaking this is the reason for the failure.

Now in your case, if you want to load the whole application context, consider using `@SpringBootTest`. You'll also have to think about the database that should be accessible during the test.